# After launching .sh script appearing 'must be connected to a terminal'

Tags: debian, sh

i have a short bash script which can run a file.
When im trying to start this by "x.sh start", there is appearing a warning 'must be connected to a terminal'. How to start this? I tried some configs of chmods.
This script is in /usr/local/bin
Im now on root, on my Debian 7 vps.

```
  #!/bin/bash

server_start() {
screen /usr/share/s/x.sh &
}

server_stop() {
killall x.sh
killall xx
}

server_restart() {
server_stop
sleep 1
server_start
}
case "$1" in
'start')
server_start

;;
'stop')
server_stop
;;
'restart')
server_restart
;;
*)
echo "usage $0 start|stop|restart"
esac
```

Comment: Note that your script will leave useless screen sessions open for every stop/restart of your service. Using `nohup` or [`start-stop-daemon`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/start-stop-daemon.8.html) instead would be better.

Answer (score 6):

`screen` requires a terminal.

If you want to start a new session in detached mode, then you want to add the `-d -m` arguments to screen.

Answer (score 1):

Your screen call is wrong. Screen require `$STY` environment variable (`-m` option prevent it.)

You must use `-d` (start detached session) and `-m` (prevent `$STY` environment variable usage) options instead of `&`  to start a daemon screen session.

[Check screen documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Start screen in detached mode:
  screen -dm /usr/share/game/startlss.sh

Comment: But screening in this patch works fine. I'm trying to start a command "lss.sh start" which is in /usr/local/bin

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone,
i added -d -m in lss.sh

```
server_start() {
screen -d -m /usr/share/game/startlss.sh &
```

Everything works fine now!

Comment: If one of the answers solved your problem, accept the answer, this will also mark your question as solved. Don't post someone elses solution as your own.